# Can't build dockerfile, created from openjdk jdk image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux, openjdk-11

I'm trying to created a dockerfile from a adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jdk-11.0.11_9-alpine image, but it fails right at the end of FROM section. I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOError: java.io.IOException: Unable to parse columns
```

and i guess that's related to this [invocation](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/blob/master/11/jdk/alpine/Dockerfile.hotspot.releases.full#L83):

I'm doing it docker locally (docker for windows 4.1.1. So the build from Dockerfile fails even if it contains a single string:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jdk-11.0.11_9-alpine
```

Could anyone help me to point out what's going on there?

Comment: Linux images can't run on Windows unless you use a Linux VM. Do you have Docker setup with WSL2?

Comment: Yes, exactly, i have a docker and WSL 2 is enabled

Comment: What command do you issue, when you get the error?

Comment: upd: i've managed to reproduce this with commands:  docker build -t jdk11 .  && docker run -d -it jdk11. The Dockerfile contains only one line: FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jdk-11.0.11_9-alpine

Comment: @bajiepka13 did you solve this problem ? I get same error when trying to run adoptopenjdk11/jdk9

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue. I have no idea what the cause is, but for me my docker image was using an image like "eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine". By removing the "alpine" part such that it becomes "eclipse-temurin:17-jdk" it seems to have fixed the problem. It would still be nice to see an explanation if anyone who comes across this can offer one.